# How can I transfer data from a UITableView to another view controller if the UITableView has cells divided into sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So say for example, I have a class called "Animals" that has separate arrays of dogs breeds, cat breeds, and so on. On the first view controller, I have a UITableView that has the cells with the different animal names divided into sections based on their classification.

If you click on a cell, it should take you to the next view controller and you should see a picture with a label corresponding to the animal name and breed. I only know how to do that when there are no sections and I'm pulling something from a single array from the Animals class. So I would do it in the didLoad() function like

```
        animalPic.image = UIImage(named: Animals.dogs[myIndex] + ".jpg")

    animalLabel.text = Animals.dogs[myIndex]
```

I know it would have to be something like "if section == 0 [input previous code here]" and so on but I'm honestly lost on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, data is your Main Array then you can do like this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let tmpArray = data[indexPath.section]
    let object = tmpArray[indexPath.row];
}
```

Here object is the element containing your values. Above code will be changed depending on your requirement.